# How do you read GeoTiff-file in SAGA GIS Program?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, import, saga

I'm very new with all GIS-stuff and I got advice that SAGA GIS would be a good program to start with. I would like to read a GeoTiff-file in SAGA, but I can't find an "import file"-function x)

Any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope, you got an answer before, but anyways:

Modules -> Import/Export - GDAL/OGR -> Import Raster

HTH,

Answer (score 1):

You can a nice tutorial about basic imagery on SAGA at this link: http://dst-iget.in/tutorials/IGET_RS_001/IGET_RS_001%20Introduction%20to%20SAGA.pdf

Comment: not a problem, I was looking for the same and I found it ;)